# When Using Redux Provider The React App goes Blank

Tags: reactjs, web, redux, frontend, store

This Works Fine But When I wrap my App in Provider react app goes blank

```
   import React from "react";
   import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
   import "./index.css";
   import App from "./App";

   const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
   root.render(
   <React.StrictMode>
   <App />
   </React.StrictMode>
   );
```

App wrapped in Provider Code

```
   import React from "react";
   import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
   import "./index.css";
   import App from "./App";
   import {Provider} from "reacct-redux"
   import store from "./store"

   const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
   root.render(
   <Provider store={store}>
     <App />
   </Provider>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should import the redux provider like this:

```
  import { Provider } from "react-redux"
```